# first time if target.address using

Tags: excel

this is the first time I am trying to use a if target.address macro.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$1:$A$20 Then
    If Target.Value > "0" Then Range("B1:B20").Value = Date
    If Target.Value <= "0" Then Range("B1:B20").Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

my idea is that when I enter something in Cell A1 the date of today gets pasted in the cell B1,
Same with A2 - B2 and so on, I got it running when I only entered one Cell like A1 and B1 but I need it for multiple cells, all in Column A and B starting row 7.

Any idea how that works? Sorry I am pretty new to the topic.

best regards
Phur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code would only work if you changed the entire range A1:A20 in one go.

If you want to check if a cell in that range has changed use Intersect and to refer to the cell in column B of the same row as the changed cell use Offset.

So something like this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$A$1:$A$20")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value > 0 Then
            Target.Offset(, 1).Value = Date
        ElseIf Target.Value <= 0 Then
            Target.Offset(, 1).Value = ""
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you I will work with that one and change it to the cells and rows I need it, that helped me a lot, many thanks again.

Comment: Hey, any idea how I can combine this macro with mine?

Comment: It's not a macro it's event code. What do you want to combine it with?